# build indicator fractals with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
<DATE>,<TIME>,<PRICE>
20200702,110000,207.2400000
20200702,120000,207.4400000
20200702,130000,208.2400000
20200702,140000,208.8200000
20200702,150000,208.0700000
20200702,160000,208.8100000
20200702,170000,209.4300000
20200702,180000,208.8700000
20200702,190000,210.0000000
20200702,200000,209.6900000
20200702,210000,209.8700000
20200702,220000,209.8000000
20200702,230000,209.5900000
20200703,000000,209.6000000
20200703,110000,211.1800000
20200703,120000,209.3900000
20200703,130000,209.6400000
```

I want to add here 2 another boolean columns called 'Up Fractal' and 'Down Fractal'.

It is stock market indicator Fractals with period 5.

It means:

0. Script runs from first row to last.
1. Script takes current row and looks at PRICE.
2. Script takes 5 previous rows and 5 next rows.
3. If PRICE of current row is maximum it is called 'Up Fractal'. True value in column 'Up Fractal'
4. If PRICE of current row is minimum it is called 'Down Fractal'. True value in column 'Down Fractal'

On stock market chart it looks something like this (this is an example from internet, not about my DataFrame)

[image]

It is easy for me to find fractals using standart methods of python. But I need high speed of pandas.

Help me please. I am very new to pandas library.

Comment: What happens to the first five and last five rows in your dataframe?

Comment: @Francis Webb, they are False because cannot be counted.

Comment: All I can think of is iterating over sets of ten rows at a time and adding new columns min/max from previous ten rows. Then could apply a lambda function that checks whether a value is equal to either of the two - but this will still have to iteratively go through your dataframe and so won't have the same 'pandas speed ups'

Comment: Share current method You've developed in Pandas. Then we can know what can be improved in termt of execution time.

Answer (score 0):

```
from binance.spot import Spot
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cl = Spot()
    r = cl.klines("BTCUSDT", "5m", limit = "100")
    df = DataFrame(r).iloc[:, :6]
    df.columns = list("tohlcv")

    # number of rows to calculate fractal
    n = 10

    df = df.astype({'t': int})
    df = df.astype({'o': float})
    df = df.astype({'h': float})
    df = df.astype({'l': float})
    df = df.astype({'c': float})

     
    # the first way
    df['uf'] = (df['h'] == df['h'].rolling(n+n+1, center=True).max())
    df['df'] = (df['l'] == df['l'].rolling(n+n+1, center=True).min())

    # the second way
    df['upfractal'] = np.where(df['h'] == df['h'].rolling(n+n+1, center=True).max(), True, False)
    df['downfractal'] = np.where(df['l'] == df['l'].rolling(n+n+1, center=True).min(), True, False)
  
    print(df)
   
    df.to_csv('BTC_USD.csv')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).